# Parsing simple JSON without grep -oP possibility

Tags: shell, awk, json

Here is my JSON:

```
{"login":"WG1118412764OA","password":"9Hv1zd74nKhYovZa"}
```

I have very basic grep, no Python, no Perl, and no jq obviously, just awk and sed.

Could somebody give me a hand on that?

I need to have login and password values as shell variables.

Thanks

Kal800

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/499094/kal800) you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and then fix that.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to `cut` if you want `builtin` tools only ;-)

```bash
OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS='"'
set -- $(<file)
IFS="$OLD_IFS"

login=$4
password=$8
```

or even:

```bash
IFS='"' read -r a b c login d e f password g < file
```

Note, that a slight change of your input `json` or a `"` inside the password would be an issue.

Better use a proper `json` parser e.g. `jq`. And if you don't have that, install it or let an admin install it for you. Always have the right tools for your tasks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have all of the mandatory POSIX tools, not just awk, sed, and grep, you could just use `cut` for input such as you show:

```
$ login=$(cut -d'"' -f4 file)
$ passwd=$(cut -d'"' -f8 file)
$ echo "$login"
WG1118412764OA
$ echo "$passwd"
9Hv1zd74nKhYovZa
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases that doesn't work for.

Comment: Thanks!!!! It was so easy :) I would have spent an hour on that at least!

Comment: You're welcome. Give it some time to see if you get a better answer and then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Comment: @Kal800 can you be certain you will never have `"` in the password?

Comment: If you could have `"` in your password as @terdon asks (any why couldn't you?) then include that case in your sample input so we can see what it'd look like in the input (presumably escaped in some way) and show the associated expected output as it probably wont be identical to the input.

Comment: With bash (or any shell supporting `<()`), you can simplify to `IFS='"' read login pass < <(cut -d'"' -f4,8 file)`. And if your `cut` has `--output-delimiter`, you can further simplify to `read login pass < <(cut -d'"' --output-delimiter=' ' -f4,8 file)`.

Comment: I'm creating those passwords myself in my API, so I'm sure they will not contain anything fancy.

Comment: Then why do you create a `json` if you don't have the tools to parse it properly and not a shell script that you can just source, e.g. `login=...; password=...`  ?

Comment: @Kal800 It seems rather strange to create a JSON document from some data, only to parse the data out from the JSON document, especially if you don't have any sensible JSON parsing tools at hand. What is the sense of creating the JSON document in the first place?

Comment: That API serves different purposes and different recipients are involved. One of them is small OpenWrt router that has to get this data but does not have the tools which other devices in the environment have.

Comment: @Kal800 `jq` is available for OpenWrt: https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/jq

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704622/parsing-simple-json-without-grep-op-possibility#comment1333135_704623), it is mentioned that the system this task is to be performed on is an OpenWrt router.  Since [`jq` is available](https://openwrt.org/packages/pkgdata/jq) for OpenWrt, it seems like a good idea to use it to extract the wanted data:

```bash
eval "$(jq -r '"login=\(.login|@sh); password=\(.password|@sh)"' file)"
```

This uses `jq` to create two shell assignments. When evaluated, the assignments assign the decoded and quoted username and password to the two shell variables `login` and `password`.

Or, if you want to parse the file twice:

```bash
login=$(jq -r '.login' file)
password=$(jq -r '.password' file)
```